# Determine the hour diffrence between 2 dateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I need to determine how many hours that are "NightHours" in a period, where '"NightHours" are between 22.00 and 6.00. My code so far:

```
Public Function() GetAmountOfNightHours as int32
    Dim firstNightHour as int32 = 22
    Dim lastNightHour as int32 = 6
    Dim begin As New DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 21, 0, 0)
    Dim end  = begin.AddHours(6)
    Return Math.Max(end.Hour - firstNightHour, 0) + Math.Min(end.Hour, lastNightHour)
End function
```

result in this case should be 5

I think its got to be something like this. but for the moment in only returns the hours from the "end day " But the problem is that the period overlaps 2 days
I tryed TimeSpan etc.

Comment: Show us the bit of your code which tries to take account of the definition of "night hours", so we can simply copy & paste to reproduce your problem for ourselves.

Comment: Also, is this simply to take account of a single "shift work pattern" when it would only span a single night, or could it span several days? e.g. should it be able to handle adding not simply 6 hours but maybe 100 hours?

Comment: Wouldn't the result be 6?

Comment: It only have to span 1day because the max. period is 24h

Comment: The result has to be 5 because, the first hour is still a "Dayhour"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, and before we even get to the algorithm, the syntax for the function signature isn't even right. Parentheses go after the name of the function, not the word Function itself. Also, you should ask for your start and end times as arguments.

Those two issues addressed, we can finally start to look at how to actually do this. I tend to look for linq-ish solution to this kind of problem:

```
Public Function GetNightHours(ByVal Start As DateTime, ByVal Finish As DateTime) As Integer
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, CInt((Finish - Start).TotalHours)).
        Select(Function(h) Start.AddHours(h)).
        Where(Function(t) t.Hour < 6 OrElse t.Hour >= 22).
        Count()
End Function
```

Note that was technically only one complete line of code. But more traditional code works just fine, too:

```
Public Function GetNightHours(ByVal Start As DateTime, ByVal Finish As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    While start < Finish
        If start.Hour < 6 OrElse start.Hour >= 22 Then result += 1
        start = start.AddHours(1)
    End While
    Return result
End Function
```

You probably also want to add a check to the beginning of these functions that the start time really is before the stop time.

Comment: +1 for the much nicer implementation, although shouldn't it be `t.Hour <= 6 OrElse t.Hour > 22`, since 05:00-06:00 should count, but 21:00-22:00 should not?

Comment: Check it again: I had AndAlso instead of OrElse for a while.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even notice that part - I was thinking about the comparisons `<=` vs `<` and `>` vs `>=`, but maybe I just need to dump the results of the where to see what it's producing. Updated previous comment.

Comment: Just to clarify, your LINQ version is counting 10pm, 11pm, 12am, 1am and 2am, but at 10pm, no night hours have been worked, and the shift ends at 3am (6 hours from 9pm), so 3am should count.  Same result in the end, I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a brute force approach, and loop through the hours in the range.  It shouldn't take too long, for a reasonable range.

**Update**

Added a version that takes two dates.

```
Sub Main
    Dim nightHours As Int32 = GetAmountOfNightHours(New DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 21, 0, 0), 6)
    Dim nightHours2 As Int32 = GetAmountOfNightHours(New DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 21, 0, 0), New DateTime(2014, 5, 7, 3, 0, 0))
End Sub

Public Function GetAmountOfNightHours(start As DateTime, count As Int32) as Int32
    Dim firstNightHour As Int32 = 22
    Dim lastNightHour As Int32 = 6
    Dim hourIterator =
        Iterator Function()
            Dim d As DateTime = start
            For i = 1 To count
                d = d.AddHours(1)
                Yield d.Hour
            Next
        End Function
    Dim nightHours = hourIterator() _
        .Where(Function(x) x > firstNightHour OrElse x <= lastNightHour) _
        .Count()
    Return nightHours
End Function

Public Function GetAmountOfNightHours(startDate As DateTime, endDate As DateTime) as Int32
    Dim firstNightHour As Int32 = 22
    Dim lastNightHour As Int32 = 6
    Dim hourIterator =
        Iterator Function()
            Dim d As DateTime = startDate
            While d < endDate
                d = d.AddHours(1)
                Yield d.Hour
            End While
        End Function
    Dim nightHours = hourIterator() _
        .Where(Function(x) x > firstNightHour OrElse x <= lastNightHour) _
        .Count()
    Return nightHours
End Function
```

Comment: Mark, thx for the respons. It is very helpfull. Now i have still have to elimined te count member because I want to compare 2 different dateTime

Comment: @NiElS A version that takes two dates is not much harder - added above.  The code is a little fragile - it should check that endDate is after startDate, etc.